# Redirect to another page after getting message from Database

Tags: php, mysql

I want to redirect to another page when and only when data from database matches with a special code. Here, I've two files name **index.php** and **load.php**. The load.php loads within index.php page 
and when the retrieved data matched with the code, the index.php page will redirect to another one.
The main prob is, **"** the load.php do't load while using **header('Location: https://qwezxc.com/');** in load.php file. **"** And it only loads after removing the location header.


 Here's the code:

**index.php**

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
setInterval(
function()
{
$('#content').load('load.php');
$("#content").animate({
    scrollTop: $("#content")[0].scrollHeight}, 300);
}, 5000);
</script>
<style>
#content{
background-color:#00A1E0;
font-size:24px;
font-weight:bold;
padding-top:10px;
color:#fff;
height: 200px;
overflow: auto;
}
#content,h1{
text-align: center;
}
</style>
<title>Auto Load Page in Div using Jquery</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Auto Load Page in Div</h1>
<div id="content"> Please wait .. </div>
</body>
<html>
```

**load.php**

```
<?php
echo ' 5 seconds ..<br/>';
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","bot") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection));
$user_array=array();
$main_array=array();
$sql_query = "SELECT * FROM `subscribe_user` WHERE  catagory LIKE '%top%';";  
$result = mysqli_query($connection,$sql_query);
while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
  if($row['catagory']=="otopo") {
    // echo "U la la la ";
     header('Location: https://qwezxc.com/');
} else {
     echo $user_array['catagory']=$row['catagory'];
     echo  "<br>";
}
array_push($main_array,$user_array);  
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem as you know with this statement

`if($row['catagory']=="otopo") {`

because the statement want to get the whole word to check not just a part of word you want to look at it,

like my example, in my database there is (Mohammed A) as element.

`$sql_query = "SELECT * FROM subscribe_user WHERE  catagory LIKE '%moha%';";`

the output is Mohammed A No, (No) its mean the output doesn't equal the whole word i searched for `$row['catagory']!="Mohammed"`

So, I recommended you to use [mysqli_num_rows()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php)

And now this is the whole file :)

```
$sql_query = "SELECT * FROM `subscribe_user` WHERE  catagory LIKE '%top%';";  
$result = mysqli_query($connection,$sql_query);
$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo $row['catagory'];// show you the element you have in database
    if($numrows > 0){
        echo " Yes";//print (Yes) if there is more than 1 element
        //header('Location: https://qwezxc.com/');//i just remove it because i want to try, i dont want to get redirect.
    }
array_push($main_array,$user_array);  
}
```

Or you can remove while if its doesn't important

```
$sql_query = "SELECT * FROM `subscribe_user` WHERE  catagory LIKE '%top%';";  
$result = mysqli_query($connection,$sql_query);
$num = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if($num > 0){
        echo " Yes";
        //header('Location: https://qwezxc.com/');
    }else{
        echo 'No';
    }
```

I hope my answer helps you :)

**EDITED**

Sorry for not noticing that you have a problem with redirect from JavaScript at first.

The second problem is `header("Location: site");`
Doesn't work with JavaScript, according to my experiences.

So you must use `<script>window.location='https://qwezxc.com/';</script>` instead of `header("Location: site");`

This is final code.

```
if($numrows > 0){
    echo "Redirecrting... <script>window.location='https://qwezxc.com/';</script>";
}
```

Comment: but  i want to get redirect.  And it loads n auto scrolls to down at the same time. i think u noticed that.
So, to get redirect, what I've to do with the codes actually... @Mohammed_Alhanafi

Comment: it doesn't, Brother. 
I think you deal with load.php,the index.php leaves alone.

Comment: @rabib_galib Hahahaha you're right xD, i just take a look in PHP code and doesn't notice the HTML one, but i edit my Answer, Check it.

Comment: @rabib_galib Your welcome brother, God bless you, inshallah